# Step 2: Review your question - This seems broken and prevents me from submitting my question

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard-2018

I am trying to submit a new question. When I clicked submit, it seemed to have put into some limbo step from which I can't proceed. On the right side, I see this:

[image]

At the bottom, the `Post your question` button is disabled, so I can't click it.

[image]

What am I supposed to do???

---

Interesting. It took me to that intermediate step when I attempted to post this meta question, but the button was not disabled. Something I just noticed that's different is that, in my screenshot above, it's nagging me about the [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath) tag, suggesting that I use it when I already did.

---

I tried removing all tags and re-entering them, but the button still wouldn't enable. I then tried removing the `disabled` attribute from the source through the inspector and was able to submit my answer. I probably just angered someone by doing that (I hated it when users create a ticket for a problem and then keep tinkering with it until they find a way around it, preventing me from reproducing the bug). Anyway, I'll keep this question up in case it helps anyone.

Per rene's comment, adding additional info:

- Browser: Version 1.13.61 Chromium: 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)
- Enabled extensions: Nimbus Screenshot
- Blockers: Brave's default
- Virus scanner: Windows Defender
- Breakfast: 170 g whole milk Greek yogurt with 1 tbsp peanut butter and a banana. Edit: Also added 3 scoops of whey protein isolate

**Edit 8/15/2020** It did it again with this question:

[Is there a way to use .NET's console app native command line parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429441/is-there-a-way-to-use-nets-console-app-native-command-line-parser)

Resolved it the same way as before by using HTML inspector to remove the `disabled` attribute from the button.

[image]

Comment: I've seen [similar reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350772/ask-question-post-button-remains-disabled). Please edit your question  to include browser, OS, any userscripts, ad blockers, virus scanners that you're using and what you had for breakfast. It would have helped if you had a developer console open when this occured as that would have revealed any errors, either javascript or network load errors.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin This has happened to me before, all I did was close out of the page(I copied the question body and title first) and then reopened the "Ask a question" page and it worked fine. Edit: Try eating something else for breakfast. Cheerios can cause bugs like these.

Comment: @10Rep did you post a bug report?

Comment: @rene I didn't know what meta was when I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61621484/why-isnt-the-deiconify-function-working) bad question.

Comment: @10Rep :D fair enough. I thought maybe you deleted the meta post. What was your browser, os,  etc? I guess you can't recall what you had for breakfast that day ...

Comment: @rene Chrome Browser, windows 10, no user scripts, and Grammarly. I had cornflakes, as always.

Comment: OT: Not too bad for breakfast. I would buff it a little more by creating [overnight oats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08MTATIFaPg) out of it though. Got to get them fibers in there when your breakfast largely consists of protein and fats. It's important to feed both the body and the gut :)

Comment: @rene I encountered the bug again. Updated this question with screenshot. Let me know if you want me to keep reporting these.

Comment: Yeah, if you encounter it and make a notion here with maybe new or different things that might pin-point the issue. Do know that sometimes you run into an issue an it never gets a resolution. For example [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244335/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-ends-in-an-error) that I kept collecting data for but the root cause was never found and in the end it had disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed as discussed at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353280/235711.

This was only happening when you entered the review step using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key due to a competing `submit` event listener.

Comment: Still happening to me in Safari, on the "Ask Different" site (ironically)

Comment: actually my issue might be different; the "Step 2" thing seems to be stuck. From the console I don't see any network activity happen.